# i want my navigation bar and its elements to grow and shrink like amazon websites navbar

Tags: html, css

This is my navbar code, but the problem is whenever i try to shrink view , the elements in the navbar are getting into next line and i am not having the proper view for my website.
iam trying to create a navbar with search bar and other elements just like one in amazon website, but the problem occuring to me is in mobile view and window size views.

```
{% load static %}



    <title>Django</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- As a link -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"
          ><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Logo-Here</a
        >

        <form class="d-flex">
          <input
            class="form-control me-2"
            type="search"
            placeholder="Search"
            aria-label="Search"
          />
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        <nav class="nav">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            ><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i> Sign-In</a
          >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            ><i class="fa-solid fa-truck-arrow-right"></i> Return & Orders</a
          >
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"
            ><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> Cart</a
          >
        </nav>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
      <div
        id="carouselExampleIndicators"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="0"
            class="active"
            aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"
          ></button>
          <button
            type="button"
            data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
            data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"
          ></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active c-item">
            <img
              src="{%static './app/images/img-1.jpg' %}"
              class="d-block w-100 c-img"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img
              src="{%static './app/images/img-2.jpg' %}"
              class="d-block w-100 c-img"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item c-item">
            <img
              src="{%static './app/images/img-3.jpg' %}"
              class="d-block w-100 c-img"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

    {% comment %} Here goes the cards for products {% endcomment %}

    <div class="container">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
        <img
          src="{%static './app/images/product-1.jpg' %}"
          class="card-img-top"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <footer class="bg-dark py-5 mt-5">
      <div class="container text-light text-center">
        <p class="display-5 mb-3">TruCart</p>
        <small> &copy; Copyright by Mk. All rights reserved. </small>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

i tried having rem units instead of px, but couldnt find the solutions.[navbar when shrink view.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oENtv.jpg)